# comparing Instants in Java8

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream, comparator, icomparable

I have this object:

```
public class MatchEvent implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    private Instant dateReceived;

    public Instant getDateReceived() {
        return dateReceived;
    }


    public void setDateReceived(Instant dateReceived) {
        this.dateReceived = dateReceived;
    }

}
```

that I want to get it ordered by date received;

```
matchService
            .findAllByDay(today)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::dateReceived))
```

but is seems that is not possible because I got a compilation error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments 
     (MatchEvent::dateReceived)
    - The type MatchEvent does not define dateReceived(T) that is applicable here
```

Comment: dateReceived is a private field. You need a public `getDateReceived()` **method** in order to use a **method** reference: `Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare a public method named `getDateReceived()` inside `class MatchEvent` as follows:

```
public Instant getDateReceived(){
    return dateReceived;
}
```

Then you can use this method as method reference as follows:

```
Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived)
```