# get the last non null object from List of objects

Tags: java-8

I have a List of objects and want to get the last element from List for which property "personStatus" value is not null.

```
List<Person> personList = getAllPersons();
List<Person> personActive = personList.stream().filter(person -> person.getPersonStatus()!=null);
```

I tried the above code which gives List of Person whose status is not null, but i want to get the last **Person** object with status not null.

Comment: Reverse the list.

Comment: looking with java8 stream

Comment: Reverse the list then use a Java 8 stream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)

Answer (score 0):

You solved 80%: first collect and filter. This will give a new collection using Java 8 streams.

#### Literally: last

Then pick **the last** from the filtered collection, e.g. on `list` using `list.get(lastIndex)` where `int lastIndex = list.size()-1` .

The *last* is a bit ambiguous, so I have 2 approaches ️

```java
List<Person> personList = getAllPersons();
// typo: name of List should be plural e.g. `personActiveList` or `activePersons`
List<Person> personActive = personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getPersonStatus()!=null)
    .toList();

// the last in order of appearance
Person lastInActiveList = personActice.get(personActice.size()-1); // may throw NPE if list empty


// the last who was active by some Instant timestamp
List<Person> sortByLastActive = personList.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getPersonStatus()!=null)
    .sorted(Person::getTimestamp())  # sort by Instant property
    .toList();

Person lastRecentlyActice = sortByLastActive.get(sortByLastActive.size()-1); // may throw NPE if list empty
```

Note: For brevity I used [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) as terminator (since Java 16).

You could also use `collect(Collectors.toList())` from older Java versions. Beware: [Differences of Java 16's Stream.toList() and Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969919/differences-of-java-16s-stream-tolist-and-stream-collectcollectors-tolist)

**⚠️ Caution:** all random `get` operations on list can throw a `NullPointerException` (NPE) if the list is empty. This should be tested using `if (list.isEmpty())` before to prevent illegal access.

#### Trick: reverse to first

The trick here as [commented by Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353542/get-the-last-non-null-object-from-list-of-objects/69353752#comment122581020_69353542) is to reverse the list before opening the stream, thus before it becomes filtered/collected as result. Afterwards you can directly pick the first.

```java
List<Person> personActiveReversed = Collections.reverse(personList).stream()  // reverse to get last elements first
    .filter(person -> person.getPersonStatus()!=null)
    .toList();

// may throw NPE if list empty
Person last = personActiveReversed.get(0);

// safer: directly on stream
Optional<Person> last = Collections.reverse(personList).stream()  // reverse before streaming
    .filter(person -> person.getPersonStatus()!=null)
    .findFirst();  // originally the last or empty 

// evaluate optional
if (last.isPresent()) {
   System.out.println("found the last: " + last.get());
} else {
   System.out.println("nobody found at last :(");
}
```

Explained:

- see comments by Boris below and on question: use [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) before `.stream` to reverse an ordered list (from last to first). Then `reversedList.get(0)` will get the originally last element.
- [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) is the new terminator, returning Java 8 type-wrapper `Optional`. This is null-safe but requires a further test or convenience-methods like [`orElse(defaultObject)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-), e.g. `last.orElse(null)`.

#### See also

- [collections - comparing Instants in Java8 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903203/comparing-instants-in-java8)
- [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort),   comparing a `peopleList`
- [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order), contains answer 'How NOT to do it': e.g. **don't use ⚠️ lambda `(a, b) -> -1`** to reverse the elements in stream (swapping). It violates `Comparator` contract and might break depending on underlying implementation.
- [How to get ordered stream from a list in reverse order in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403614/how-to-get-ordered-stream-from-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-java-8), interesting discussion on generic list sorting
- [How to Get the Last Element of a Stream in Java? | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-last-element), alternatives using `skip` or `reduce` with warning note on stream types

Comment: Your comparator is invalid, it needs to be symmetric - otherwise sorting behaviour is undefined and can throw and error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with “sequential”. The broken comparator happens to provide the intended result due to implementation details of the *sorting algorithm* used behind the scenes. Since this sorting algorithm is intentionally unspecified, this comparator may produce unintended results in a different implementation or fail with an exception, regardless of whether the Stream is sequential or not. A well known example of the past were broken comparators failing with exceptions when Java 7 was introduced. Some occurrences might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/11441666)…

Answer (score -1):

```
int lastNotNull = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < personList.size();i++){
    if(person.getPersonStatus()!=null)
        lastNotNull = i;
}
```

lastNotNull is the index of the last not null Person

Comment: Hint: if you search the other way you can terminate early.